# 15 month old - developmental activities? Dealing with night terrors?

Tags: toddler, development, teaching, bedtime

My daughter is almost 15 months old. Are there things i could work on her with? Cleaning? Talking? Potty training? Anything else along these lines that I could start working on with her? And any suggestions on night terrors? She is up 3-6 times a night, not necessarily awake, just crying in her sleep.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please feel free to ask more than one question, but try not to ask such unrelated questions in the same post. You should really split these up.

Comment: Does she sleep in the same room as you? When my younger girl was crying so many times at night it about drove us insane. When we moved her to her sisters room and removed her mom from any night activities she stopped. I think the crying while asleep was like an automated response to nurse and not so much night terrors. She was about 16 months or so when we made the move.

Comment: If you use the search function, you will see we have answers on all these topics. Have a look through existing posts first, then see if you need to ask anything else.

Answer (score 3):

With a 15 month old baby /toddler, the most important lesson is **life**.

That said, do not worry about "lessons" or "training", but teach her by example. Take her with you wherever you go, *include* her in what you are doing (instead of just having her in the stroller) and let her experience the real world.

I'm a stounch supporter of the the theory that children learn 24/7 and need to use as many of their senses as possible:

- The best way to teach a small child new words is to use them when naming real world things. So instead of reading a picture book at home (which is good, of course!), name and describe the apples you are buying at the store. (How many words / adjectives can you come up with? Challenge yourself a bit!) Talk a lot and be precise with your choice of words, don't hesitate to use "big" words, when appropriate. Once she can speak better, ask and *actively listen* a lot. too.
- The best way to teach (better: let experience) a child math, is to count said apples while putting them in the cart or counting the eggs for a cookie. Later (ok, in a few years), cut up a pie for an idea how the concept of fractions works.
- Scrambled eggs (going from liquid to solid) or dish soap (dissolving fat from dishes, making bubbles) give a first glimpse at chemistry.
- A rainbow, a mirror and a lens, even the curved surface of a spoon introduce the concept of optics - even if you will not name or explain the theories behind for a looong while.
- ...

All these things should not be pesented as "lesson", but simply as observation - I encourage you to ask her about her observations and how she explains them to herself once she speaks better (pre-school, perhaps), you will gleam valuable insights on how your daughters mind works!

(I'm not going to adress the second question, as this *really* should be a separate question.)